# How to find my transaction from root of Merkle Tree

Tags: transactions, merkle-tree

How could I verify my transaction from the root of Merkle Tree.

Comment: You can't with just the root of the tree. You need both the root and the path to have a proof.

Comment: @vrnvav97 the tx that you want verify is on mainnet or testnet? If yes could you post the tx id so we can show a complete working example?

Comment: @darosior ok so i need a path also to verify my tx.

Comment: @aqquadro its nowhere, i was clearing my doubts. But can u show any other working example?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use `gettxoutproof`

```
$ bitcoin-cli help gettxoutproof
gettxoutproof ["txid",...] ( "blockhash" )

Returns a hex-encoded proof that "txid" was included in a block.
...
```

you receive data including your transaction id with another txids (privacy purpose).
then you need create empty merkle tree and place txids inside leafs, check this [link](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-examples#parsing-a-merkleblock) to know how you can do it. You need to work even with little and big endian

After that you have to concat leafs and do SHA256 twice until the merkle root.